# Terminal not clearing after auto start bashscript in raspbian wheezy

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, omxplayer

I'm using a raspberry pi 2 to show all the video's in a folder. The raspberry automatically boots up (with a generic electric timer) in to console (not the gui) and after it boots it runs a bashscript I found [here](http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/). This bashscript contains an infinite loop to play all the videos in a folder using omxplayer.

When I boot in to consolemode and manually start the script everything works perfectly. The terminal screen clears, the first video starts, and after it ends there is a second or two of black screen (empty terminal) and the second video starts playing. This is **exactly** what I want.

However, when I use crontab to start this script (@reboot /path/to/script.sh) the terminal messages stay and it doesn't clear everything between video's.

I've tried creating my own script that first clears everything, and then calls the second script. But this doesn't work.

I'm really really new in this field (but I'm having fun) so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

P.S. I edited the /boot/cmdline.txt file so it doesn't display critical kernal logs as a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this using cron. You should be changing the inittab so that it runs outside any environment that may be created. See the `inittab(5)` man page for details. You may also be interested in `openvt(1)` as well.